# Antlr4, cannot resolve symbol 'PlSqlParser'

Tags: intellij-idea, plsql, antlr4

I am new to Antlr4 and trying to generate a parser for PL/SQL with the g4 file I downloaded from Github. However, I encounter a problem while using the auto-generated codes in IntellJ IDEA with the Antlr plugin. I have the parser file in my directory but it still pops up errors stating that cannot resolve symbol 'PlSqlParser'. What should I do with it to fix this error?

[Cannot resoleve symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aELiL.png)

[PlSqlParser in the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYRtH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question here. It seems to be that IDEA is ignoring this parser file since the size of it is too large. I fixed it by editing the custom properties.

Comment: Editing how? What to change in it?